# Data file too short - Arma II: OA

Tags: steam, arma-2

I just downloaded Arma 2 OA, and upon launch, it gave me the message that the data file anims.pbo was too short.

I tried verifying the integrity of the files through steam, and it tells me 1 file was found to be corrupted and will be replaced, then it does nothing.

Please help me find a solution.

Comment: Locate anims.pbo file in the game folder and delete it before trying the "verification of integrity".
Note: run steam as Administrator.

Comment: @Null_Error Have you tried George's advice?